# .NET Core 6 handle int on controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a basic apicontroller. I can handle any model on my design. But I can't handle int or string.

There is my code

```
[Route("Get"),HttpPost]
        public async Task<JResultModel> Get(int id)
        {
            if (id == -1)
            ....
            return _JResult.Control(model);
        }
```

And AJAX post

```
$.ajax({
        url: postUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (resultData) {
            console.log(resultData);
            return resultData;
        }
    });
```

I want to get both models and types.

Comment: **** postUrl is dynamic string. I can trigger my controller. there is not problem.

Comment: What's your data look like ? Could you share your code about data?

Comment: data is a simple object. it can be a int, array or a model. i want to generic.

Comment: Off-topic: You call with `method:POST`, you tag with `[HttpPost]`, but you name it ... *Get*?

Comment: Your `data` *must* match your parameter - ie `data: { id: 123 }` (or JSON'd if necessary).   It can't be "generic" if your parameter is `int id`

Comment: @freedomn-m it is not about post type. its about Model Crud works.

Comment: Errr? CRUD = Create Read Update Delete - no post *or* get there - I think you're mixing this with REST which uses http verbs POST and GET.   It's up to you if you want to give your actions conflicting names.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no model then you don't even have explicitly type the dataType or contentType there do this instead.

```
  ** $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "Your Url",
    data: {
        ParameterNameInController: Value
    },
    success: function (result) {
       console.log(result)
        })
    },
    Error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})**
```